# Do we need a "post-apocalyptic" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

I looked through [Restoring the world after a global apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/6889/restoring-the-world-after-a-global-apocalypse) a few minutes ago, and noticed the [apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocalypse) tag. It suits the question, but the question itself isn't so much about the apocalypse as events *after* the apocalypse - as you can imagine.

There are a whole bunch of other [apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocalypse) questions - and many are in the same vein as this one - that are really post-apocalyptic. Therefore, I propose a tag for them, phrased as either

[post-apocalyptic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-apocalyptic)

or, in keeping with [apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocalypse),

[post-apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-apocalypse).

Is this a good idea?

Comment: I was going to answer but Michael's answer has covered everything I was going to say. I say we do that.

Comment: I've gone through al of the questions, so I think the transfer is done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a worthwhile idea to try out to me.

I would suggest going with [post-apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-apocalypse) and using the tag wiki excerpt to make it clear when each should be used. That way, someone typing `apocalypse` into the tags field will be offered both and immediately see a short description of when each should be used.